# Get rid of the message 'Changed current directory to /home/MYUSERNAME/.composer'

Tags: composer-php, drush

**Problem/Motivation**

On ubuntu 14.04 when I open a new terminal window or tab I get this message:

> Changed current directory to /home/MYUSERNAME/.composer

I installed drush via composer:

http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install-alternative/#install-a-global-drush-via-composer

Why is that happening and how can I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance ;)